# Assign null values to SQL parameters

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have an application that has a gridview. The population of this particular gridview is optional, so when the page is saved, if the gridview is not populated, it throws an error in the stored proc, stating too many parameters. So, the question is, how do I assign null values to the stored proc when the gridview is not populated? The user would check a box, then populate the gridview, otherwise, the checkbox is not checked and null values should be assigned to the gridview fields through the stored proc.

Comment: post your sproc param declaration SQL code

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server stored procedures (I assume SQL Server, you don't specify in your Q) can give default values to your parameters as so:

#### I am making up scenario because your question is lacking details

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ProcName(
    @Name VARCHAR(50) = NULL  //<- default to NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
   IF @Name IS NULL BEGIN
     SELECT TOP(1) * FROM dbo.Table  
   END
   ELSE BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM dbo.Table WHERE Name LIKE @Name + '%' 
   END
END
```

#### Default parameter values are ONLY used if the parameter is NOT PASSED, if you pass @Name then the procedure will use what you send.

**Execution:**
In code you simply do not add parameters and let the stored procedure handle it.

Comment: ok, it obviously depends on the size of param list, but defaults are nice and my point about not sending the param is the only way to use a default parameter value

Comment: @TMcKeown That is an interesting idea. What is the effect on cached execution plans if you don't pass a parameter: does SQL Server make a new plan for a query where a parameter is not passed?

Comment: SQL server plans are based on what parameters are passed so it could affect it but without knowledge of your indices/schema it's hard for me to say.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all..the  @Name VARCHAR(50) = NULL  is what I was looking for..